# How do Razor Walls in a Grid-based 1st person "Blobber" RPG work?

Tags: game-engine, software-design

I am struggling to find a way to even ask this question. It might be clearer if you look at the Glossary I am getting my terms from: http://crpgaddict.blogspot.com/p/glossary.html

This is an example of "Razor Walls", this is what I am trying to do:

[image: This is an example of "Razor Walls"]

This is an example of "Worm Tunnel Walls", this is the other approach:

[image: This is an example of "Worm Tunnel Walls"]

In "Worm Tunnel Walls" I would use a 2D array. Each index in the array would either be a wall or a floor, pretty easy.

I am having a harder time figuring out how to conceptualize Razor walls. I have tried some different approaches, such as making the array of a custom type so that each cell tracked whether or not each of the edges had a wall, but you want adjacent cells to share a wall, which means walls have to be stored in two cells, which seems inefficient.
Then I tried setting up a 2D array and making all the even numbers walls, and all the odd numbers floors, but I am having to code a LOT to make that work in the various edge case.
I can make either of these approaches work, of course, but it feels klunky.
Pool of Radiance did this in 1988 on Amiga! It has been a standard way to make these games for decades on machines with serious memory and processing limitations. It seems like there should be a more elegant approach that I am missing.

Comment: You just need two bits per cell, one indicating a wall to the top, one indicating a wall to the left.  To see if there's a wall to the right, look at the left wall bit for the cell to the right (and similarly for the bottom wall).  You need an empty row & column of cells at the bottom and right of the maze, so that you have somewhere to store the rightmost and bottommost walls.

Comment: So for a map that is 15x15, you bump the map to 16x16 and you are storing walls in 32 bits. when you want to check collision down or right, you just check the relevant bit in the adjacent cell.
I like it! that sounds like what I am missing. I wish you had put it in a solution, so I could hit the check-mark.

Comment: @JasonHarper: Tested it, that definitely is the superior solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have another idea.
I am thinking 3 2D arrays.

1. Array one stores floor information.
2. Array two stores Up-Down wall information.
3. Array three stores left-right wall information.

So my map is 8x8. The first room is floor[0,0] with walls at UDWall[0,0] and UDWall[1,0] and walls at LRwall[0,0] and LRWall[0,1]

I am on mobile right now, but I will try it later and report back.